# Appcelerator - Create iOS App name starting with $

Tags: appcelerator

I am trying to create an application with the name starting with $, for example $money. Now when I am trying to create an AdHoc build, it fails during the build. But when I try to run it in Simulator it is working fine. Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you please share the error that you get when the build fails?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the section about "App Name Localization" in the documentation:

https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Internationalization-section-src-29004892_Internationalization-AppNameLocalization

It allows you to have foreign letters as an app name, might be useful for $ too